# Java N-Level Nested Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm wondering if there's anything that allows N-Level nested generics?

Suppose I have

```
class Example< A > {
    ...
}
```

Is there any trick to get

```
Example<Example<Example<Example<Example<Example<...A...>>>>>>>
```

when the program is running (i.e. not hardcoding it)?

The reason I'm wondering about this is because I parameterized the coefficients of a univariate Polynomial class - so I had Polynomial< C >, where C is the type of coefficient, and C could be Integer, Rational, Polynomial (this would solve multivariate Polynomial issues), or a lot of other things. Having

```
Polynomial< Polynomial< Integer > >
```

for two variable polynomials might be okay, but if it gets to an arbitrary number of variables, I'd be in trouble. I realize this is probably bad design. Is there any way to resolve this issue (aside from restart)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Generics are purely compile-time.  That wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: You should use regular polymorphism.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to the actual question, but you say `when the program is running` due to type erasure, generic type information is lost at runtime. If you are infact not trying to do this at runtime, I don't why what you have won't work.

Comment: I never knew that generics were "purely compile-time." I think that resolves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a way to approach this problem using parametric recursion. It doesn't give you exactly N nested parametrization, but it addresses the problem of having to type

```
Example< Example < Example< ... ... > > > >
```

I stumbled upon an article on this topic today: http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~studia-i/2011-4/02-Niculescu.pdf

Skip down to section 4 for the part about Java Generics. Below is what I got from the article's discussion on parametric recursion, and a coding experiment I tried.

I never thought about trying something like this:

```
public interface RingElem< T extends RingElem< T > > {

    public abstract RingElem< T > add( RingElem< T > e );

    public abstract RingElem< T > multiply( RingElem< T > e );
}
```

I didn't realize you could parametrize an interface with something that extended "itself." Now, if you have a `RingElem` object, then it would be parametrized by T, which is of type `RingElem`. By recursion, you pretty much have `RingElem< RingElem < RingElem < ... > > >`, but it's "infinitely" nested.

And now, you can implement the `RingElem` interface to create your own Polynomial class:

```
public class Polynomial implements RingElem< Polynomial > {

    ///...
}
```

And if you have a `Polynomial` object, it is parametrized as `Polynomial< Polynomial< ... ... > >`

When I thought about this in my head, I was skeptical that you could possibly initialize such an object. But once I started coding, it seemed simple enough. Below is are 3  classes I "hacked" together that allow one to manipulate multivariate monomials. I'll rewrite with better design (I should really be using `public interface Monomial< T extends Polynomial< T > >` where `T` is the type of coefficient for the Monomial) and add comments if I get the time.

As the example demonstrates, you can get a multivariate monomial that uses every letter of the alphabet without having to type `Monomial< Monomial< Monomial< Monomial< ... ... > > >` 26 times.

Monomial class: (e.g. 5x^2, 4a^-5)

```
public class Monomial implements RingElem< Monomial > {

    private Monomial m_coefficient;

    private Monomial m_base;

    private Monomial m_exponent;

    public Monomial() {

    }

    public Monomial( Monomial coefficient , Monomial base , Monomial exponent ) {
        if ( base.m_coefficient != null ) {
            this.m_coefficient = coefficient.multiply( base.m_coefficient );
            if ( base.m_base != null ) {
                this.m_coefficient = coefficient.multiply( base.m_base );
            }
        }
        else {
            this.m_coefficient = coefficient;
        }
        this.m_exponent = exponent;
        this.m_base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial add( RingElem< Monomial > e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Monomial ) {
            Monomial addend = (Monomial) e;
            if ( this.m_base.equals( addend.m_base ) && this.m_exponent.equals( addend.m_exponent ) ) {
                Monomial rtn = new Monomial( this.m_coefficient.add( addend.m_coefficient ) , this.m_base , this.m_exponent );
                return rtn;
            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Addition would produce a polynomial, which is not implemented yet!" );
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation not defined" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial multiply( RingElem< Monomial > e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Constant ) {
            Constant c = ( Constant ) e;
            return new Monomial( this.m_coefficient.multiply( c ) , this.m_base , this.m_exponent );
        }
        else if ( e instanceof Monomial ) {
            Monomial m = ( Monomial ) e;
            return new Monomial( this.m_coefficient.multiply( m.m_coefficient ).multiply( m.m_base ) , this.m_base , this.m_exponent.add( m.m_exponent ));
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation not defined" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if ( this.m_coefficient == null || this.m_base == null || this.m_exponent == null ) {
            return "<error>";
        }
        return this.m_coefficient.toString() + this.m_base.toString() + "^" + this.m_exponent.toString();
    }

    final public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String[] letters = { "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z" };
        Variable[] v = new Variable[ letters.length ];
        for ( int i=0 ; i<letters.length ; i++ ) {
            v[ i ] = new Variable( letters[ i ] );
        }
        Monomial coefficient = new Constant( 1.2 );
        Monomial exponent = new Constant( 4.5 );
        Monomial test = new Monomial( coefficient , v[ 0 ] , exponent );
        for ( int i=1 ; i<letters.length ; i++ ) {
            test = test.multiply( new Constant( 1.2 ) );
            test = new Monomial( test , v[ i ] , new Constant( (int)(Math.random() * 25 )) );
        }
        System.out.println( test.toString() );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        if ( o instanceof Monomial ) {
            Monomial m = ( Monomial ) o;
            return this.m_coefficient.equals( m.m_coefficient ) && this.m_base.equals( m.m_base ) && this.m_exponent.equals( m.m_exponent );
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Constant class: (e.g. 1, 2, 3.14159, -10000)

```
public class Constant extends Monomial {

    private double m_val;

    public Constant( double val ) {
        super();

        this.m_val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public Constant add ( RingElem e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Constant ) {
            Constant c = ( Constant ) e;
            return new Constant( this.m_val + c.m_val );
        }
        else if ( e instanceof Variable ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation would create a polynomial, which is not defined yet!" );
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation not defined" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial multiply( RingElem e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Constant ) {
            Constant c = ( Constant ) e;
            return new Constant( this.m_val * c.m_val );
        }
        else if ( e instanceof Variable ) {
            return new Monomial( this.clone() , (Variable) e , new Constant( 1 ) );
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation not defined" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf( this.m_val );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        if ( o instanceof Constant ) {
            Constant c = ( Constant ) o;
            return this.m_val == c.m_val;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Constant clone() {
        return new Constant( this.m_val );
    }
}
```

Variable class: (e.g. x, y, z)

```
public class Variable extends Monomial {

    final private String m_varName;

    public Variable( String varName ) {
        this.m_varName = varName;
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial add( RingElem e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Variable ) {
            if ( e.equals( this ) ) {
                return new Monomial( new Constant( 2 ) , this , new Constant( 1 ) );
            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Operation would create a polynomial, which is not defined yet!" );
            }
        }
        else if ( e instanceof Monomial ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Operation would create a polynomial, which is not defined yet!" );
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException( "operation not defined!" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial multiply( RingElem e ) {
        if ( e instanceof Constant ) {
            Constant c = ( Constant ) e;
            return c.multiply( this );
        }
        if ( e instanceof Variable ) {
            return new Monomial( (Variable) e , this , new Constant( 1 ) );
        }
        else {
            return this.multiply( e );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.m_varName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        if ( o instanceof Variable ) {
            Variable v = ( Variable ) o;
            return this.m_varName.equals( v.m_varName );
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```